# Loop a function without changing pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function makeid(count)
{
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    var text = "";
    for(var x=0; x<count; x++ ) {
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return text;
}
window.location = "http://robloxdatabase.x10host.com/test.php?bob="+makeid(1128)
```

Right now it does this once, then changes the page. How do I have this happen without changing pages and to have it keep going? I've heard it can be done with jquery, but I've had no success. Open to any method that makes "http://robloxdatabase.x10host.com/test.php?bob="+makeid(1128) repeat by itself.

Comment: can you explain what it is you are trying to do? This is a "problem", but we don't even know what you're after, ultimately, so it's hard to guide.

Comment: after you get the data what will you do with it?

Comment: `setInterval(refresh, 5000)` will call the function every 5 secs (but remove `get` from `.done()`.

Comment: I want makeid() to keep happening by using refresh() but i'm not using refresh() right apparently, dont know why though. don't want the browser to change webpages like i had it previously doing

Comment: Try this: $.get(Link, {}, function(data){refresh();});

Comment: I was literally almost done writing up an answer. this question is not a duplicate of the question suggested. The user wants to automatically add a string to the url regardless of the get call being made.

Comment: "refused to connect because it violates the following content security police directive: "connect-src"